# Game Maker window and room are rectangle but room is a square in testing

Tags: game-maker

I have different sized rooms in my project.  One room is a rectangle, 800by400.  I have set the window to 800 by 400 but the room comes up 400 by 400 with black spaces on the left and right side.
Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need resize window, application surface and gui size.

```
window_set_size(room_width, room_height);
surface_resize(application_surface, room_width, room_height);
display_set_gui_size(room_width, room_height);
```

(for example, in `Room start` event)

Answer (score 1):

As for the why (if that is still intresting to you ;))
Game Maker uses the dimentions of the first room that you open in the game. All other rooms will be displayed in the same window.